# LPG planner: how to increase the MAX_RELEVANT_ FACTS?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning, pddl

I'm new in using LPG planner. I'm trying to find a plan using pddl 2.2 for domain with many derived-predicates and problem with many initial "conditions". The LPG planner starts running but at some point it can't find a plan, so it can do two things:

- it loops until it kills the process after many minutes
  or
- it gives me this error message: too many relevant facts! increase MAX_RELEVANT_FACTS (currently 15000).

Does anybody know how to solve that? Where can I change that value? If it is not possible could you suggest me a different planner (possible that allows interface with c++/python) that supports a higher number of relevant facts?

I tried to decrease the number of derived predicates and in that case it can find a plan or if they're more of 15000, but not too many that it crashes, it gives me that error. But those predicates are fundamental for my work, I can't cut them in the final project.

Thank you so much, guys!

Comment: "*could you suggest me a different planner?*" can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74551667/edit) your question to add your `Domain / Problem` to see which [planner](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners) can cover the requirements of your model?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! 
You can find my domain and problem here https://github.com/IleD94/Thesis, they are: Domain_ToM_AS.pddl and problem_ToM_AS.pddl thank you. Basically, I need a planner that can manage many derived predicates with many "variables" (like: ?y in the exists "section")  (sorry maybe these terms are not technical, but I'm new in this)